# Does .load method loading full page?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to know how the JQuery/Ajax .load() method works.
I mean that I have page A.html and page B.html.

How JQuery will loading Page Fragment for A.html from B.html?

1. Loading full page and select the required element
2. Loading page until required element will not be found?

I have A.html and B.html. B.html is to large. I can create C.html and write just Page Fragments here. Will be it better? Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

jQuery's `.load()` requests and loads the entire URL you give it.  If you specify a fragment of that URL, then it will load the entire URL and then find just the fragment and throw away the rest.

For example, if you run this:

```
$("#content").load("http://example.com/mainpage #main_content");
```

then jQuery will make an Ajax request to load all of "http://example.com/mainpage".  Then, after that all arrives, it will have the DOM parse it into DOM objects and then it will search for the #main_content element and, if found, it will insert into `$("#content")`, just that piece of what it downloaded.

If you want to load smaller chunks at a time over the network, then you have to break up the source HTML into smaller pieces that can be loaded separately.  jQuery's `.load()` can't do that for you.